# Function thinks an int is a list

Tags: python, list, function, integer

I defined a function that uses the length of a list as input. It looks like this:

```
lhand = len(hand)
def roll(lhand):
    global hand
    ndice = 5 - sum(lhand)
    for i in range(ndice):
        newhand = random.randint(1, 6)
        hand = hand.append(newhand)
    return hand
```

Now, for some reason, I get an error saying that operator - is not allowed between a list and a string. This confused me as I know that lhand should be an int. I've tried to solve it by putting int() in lots of places, but I still got the same error. Even when I changed lhand in the function to a number, I still got the same error. How I solved this(I think) is by using sum(lhand) in the function. This seemed to work as it no longer gave me an error. I would still like to know why I got that error, or that maybe something else is wrong in my code for it to fail.

Thanks

Comment: Please fix the formatting, it is impossible to understand the code this way. Why is `hand` global and returned?

Comment: It doesn't seem possible for this code to cause that error. Along with fixing the indentation, please show the full error traceback.

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem probably lies in this line - `ndice = 5 - sum(lhand)`. Your `lhand` is a number, you can't use `sum` on an integer.
You should also avoid using `global`, it is always wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to BoobyTrap's comment about avoiding the use of `global`, here's how I'd recommend fixing this code: take `hand` as the parameter instead of `lhand`.

```
def roll(hand):
    ndice = 5 - len(hand)
    for i in range(ndice):
        hand.append(random.randint(1, 6))
    return hand
```

Note that when you call `hand.append()`, the `append` method modifies `hand` but returns `None`, so you don't want to reassign `hand` to its result.